# Efficiently checking date ranges in python

Tags: python, date, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas.DataFrame ("loans") with about 250,000 rows of loan data.  For each record, I have the start date ("origination_date") and end date ("end_date").  I want to identify, for a particular 30 day period, how many loans were in existence.  I've successfully managed to do that, but it seems to be very slow:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2005, 11, 1)
dates = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=int(30*i)) for i in np.arange(130)]
def in_date(loan_dates, date=dates[0]):
    orig = loan_dates[0]
    end = loan_dates[1]
    return(orig <= date and end > date)
def count_active(current_date):
    loan_filter = loans.ix[:, ('origination_date', 'end_date')].apply(
            in_date, date=current_date, axis=1)
    return(np.count_nonzero(loan_filter))
active_loans = [count_active(date) for date in dates]
```

My question is: is there a faster way to do this?  This takes 30 minutes or so in my iPython notebook, and it seems like a calculation like this shouldn't be too resource-intensive...

I'm fairly new to python, so I apologize if this is a silly question.  I've searched around StackOverflow and Google, but I haven't found any relevant answers.

Comment: Are you after [`rolling_count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_count.html)?

Comment: @EdChum Possibly...  For each month, I want to count the total number of loans that have the origination_date before that month and their end_date after that month.  Can I do that with rolling_count?

Comment: Sorry posted a comment for another question, it looks like you want to group or apply some filtering. I'm not sure at the moment whether it's better to group or use `rolling_apply`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help here.  I think you're just trying to select rows based on date?  Just check the docs, this is easy and also much faster if you follow docs and use the stuff already built into pandas instead of re-inventing the wheel with custom functions